# How to ask user input after catch block

Tags: java, exception

This is a guessing game. I want to enter user input after error message but my catch phrase keeps on printing infinitely.. please help me.
if I enter letter it will print
 "Invalid Number! Try again."
 "Invalid Number! Try again."
 "Invalid Number! Try again."
 "Invalid Number! Try again."

```
import java.util.*;
public class RandomGame {

   public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Random rand = new Random();

      int x = rand.nextInt(50);
      int counter = 0;
      int y;
      boolean flag = false;

      System.out.print("Give a number from 1-50:");

      while(!flag) {

         flag = true;
         try {    
            y = sc.nextInt();
            if (y < x) {
               counter++;
               System.out.println("Too low. Try again");
               flag = false;
            } else if (y > x) {
               counter++;
               System.out.println("Too high. Try again");
               flag = false;
            } else if (x == y) {
               counter++;
               System.out.println("you got it " + counter + " attempt(s):");
               flag = true;
            }
         } catch(InputMismatchException | NumberFormatException e1) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Number! Try again.");
         }
         flag = false;

      }

      System.out.println(x);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `nextInt` doesn't remove the offending character from the stream, so you keep encountering the same error over and over.

You'd be better to call `next` instead of `nextInt`, then try to parse the resulting `String` into an `int`, using `Integer.parseInt`.  That way, if the content of the stream is non-numeric, it will actually be removed from the stream.

Comment: can you give me example? I'm sorry I'm still noob :(

Comment: You could just replace the line `y = sc.nextInt();` with something like `String input = sc.next(); y = Integer.parseInt(input);`

Comment: I really appreciate how you help me :)

Answer (score -1):

For this kind of things you can also use the "finally" close,

```
try{}
catch(Exception e){}
finally{}
```

**finally always  works (even if there wasn't any exception)**, even if there is any exception
and it helps the program works even if there was an error.

Comment: How will using `finally` help Gray's code to break out of the infinite loop?